# SharePoint Designer 2013 Announcements WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, custom, formatting, sitefeed

I'm currently using SharePoint Designer 2013 to create a custom home page for a SharePoint site. I've created an announcements WebPart however I'm having a lot of issues formatting it. I've attached a screenshot of what it currently looks like.

My main question is: How do I stop the weird picture showing up in front of the name in the '`Created By`' column? Also, if anyone knows how I can format the title of each post I would be greatly appreciative.

[image: Image of the current state of my WebPart]

Comment: What you are seeing are the image used to show a users Skype status, that is formatted through CSS positioning to show the right/current status.. So i guess you are missing out of something.

Comment: What kind of thing would I be missing out on? Would it be a CSS format?? I'm really stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps are you using a custom master page or css on the site? Try the default master pages or even change the theme / look to see if the problem still exists.